# Android full screen theme for ICS and above

Tags: android

What Android theme should be used if I want full screen activities with white backgrounds running on devices supporting API 14+?

Comment: Can you show us whatever you have tried?

Comment: Add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` to the activity declaration and a white background to the root of each layout. Since we define more than one layout file for each activity, we need to add the `background` attribute to all layout files so there is the added work of checking each and every layout file developers are working on. It would be nice if we could control it from one place.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your oncreate

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```